# Remove XML headers using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```
response = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'+
                '<RDService status="READY" info="Mantra Authentication Vendor Device Manager">'+
                '<Interface id="DEVICEINFO" path="/rd/info" />'+
                '<Interface id="CAPTURE" path="/rd/capture" />'+
                '</RDService>';

response=response.toString().replace('/<\? xml .*\?>/', '').trim();
console.log(response);
```

I have an XML response, and I want to remove the headers of the XML. But my above code is not removing it. It is returning the same string in the response.

Comment: What is the code sir? Please consider it posting too.

Comment: @Helper I have shared the code, i.e., inside my Javascript Function.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the string using regex?

Comment: @Helper I want to just remove the XML header from the String.

I want to remove `<?xml version="1.0"?>` from the String.

I want this in the result:
`<RDService status="READY" info="Mantra Authentication Vendor Device Manager"><Interface id="DEVICEINFO" path="/rd/info" /><Interface id="CAPTURE" path="/rd/capture" /></RDService>`

Comment: Typo. You put a space after `<\?` so required a space between `<?` and `xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'+
            '<RDService status="READY" info="Mantra Authentication Vendor Device Manager">'+
            '<Interface id="DEVICEINFO" path="/rd/info" />'+
            '<Interface id="CAPTURE" path="/rd/capture" />'+
            '</RDService>';

//response=response.replace('/<\\?xml.*?\\?>/', '').trim();
response=response.substring(response.indexOf("?>") + 2).trim();
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
response=response.toString().replace(new RegExp('(<?.xml)(.*?)(=?>)'), '').trim();
```

Comment: Sir, I want to make it work it in a flexible way. If the header returns `<?xml version="1.0" something="value" ?>` this will not work

Comment: That was what I was asking are you trying to use regex for this to identify. :) I'll work it out just few minutes.

Comment: @PRAMITPAUL, used regex now. This won't fail ever.